# What are these "colorful" capacitors called and why are they used?

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount, decoupling-capacitor

What are these "colorful" capacitors called?  Why are they used instead of regular ceramic ones?

[image: Blue surface-mount capacitors]

Comment: I don't know what those are but I do not think they are capacitors.

Comment: Those look like surface-mount film capacitors, maybe? They're rare, but I seem to recall they look something like that.

Comment: I was going to say film capacitors too.

Comment: reasons for using non-ceramic caps: frequency response, ESR, fail mode, capacity.

Comment: My first thought was smd emi filter.

Comment: My first though was ceramic resonator as they seem to have 3 terminals, but not sure if they really have 3. But it would likey make no sense when connected to OPA317. If they are capacitors, which might be more likely, they would be special capcitors with stable and precise capcitance with low leakage, used in sensitive analog circuits. And SMD EMI filter at op-amp input might make sense too. What is the function of that device?

Comment: Blocking high freq, low pass filter. But usually the middle is interrupted on the top side, that makes me doubt.

Comment: if they are caps, they could be precision film caps, typically 1% or, as used in some filter circuits. But it's almost impossible to say just by looking.

Comment: These are definitely caps, there are lots of these on the board. ~33% blue ones, ~66% regular ceramic caps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are SMT film caps, probably PPS or similar (The issue with SMT film is that the reflow profile becomes somewhat critical, which is why you try to avoid them).

Used where relatively high values combined with good dielectric behaviour is desired as these have lower voltage coefficient than type II ceramics and lower dielectric absorption which can matter in things like sample and hold networks.

For values up to about 100nF or so, type I (C0G) dielectric ceramics are available, but these have significantly higher dielectric absorption which can matter in some applications, so sometimes a film part is preferred.

One trap with the SMT film parts is that they tend to drift initially after reflow, so if they form part of something critical that way you may with to delay calibration for a while to let them settle, learned that the hard way.

Comment: Thx! Didn’t know :)

Comment: Apparently C0G absorption can be quite good, but it varies between manufacture (maybe even batch?). It's not bad in general (most sources say <0.6%, which I'm sure are all quoting some long lost original reference, not saying so independently). Have also heard stacked SMT films are prone to high leakage (relatively speaking: ~GΩ say) after soldering, as flux gets into gaps and is impossible to wash out.